# array indexof() not working for dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery

array `indexof()` not working for dynamic value.

If use like:

```
var arr ='1,2,3,4,';
del_row = arr.slice(0,-1);
del_array = del_row.split(',');
var a = del_array.indexOf('2');
```

It works, But I am using like:

```
for(var i='1';i<=rowcnt;i++) {
    var del_row = $('#hid_delrow').val();
    if(del_row != ''){
        del_row = del_row.slice(0,-1);
        del_array = del_row.split(',');
        del_length = del_array.length;
        var a = del_array.indexOf(i);
        //var a = $.inArray(i,del_array)
        if(a != '-1'){
            continue;
        }
    }
 }
```

Its not Working, I also try:

`del_array.indexOf(parseInt(j, 10));`

and

`$.inArray(j,del_array);`

all returns value as -1 . Help me.

Comment: Works for me....

Comment: @Mr.Alien, same here..

Comment: How can i check?

Comment: @Madhan use console?  output the value of `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `del_array` is an array of strings.

`indexOf` will work when you pass a string -  `indexOf('2')` - but not when you pass an int `indexOf(i)`. The fact that you declare it as `var i = '1'` isn't enough to make it a string, because you then proceed to do integer operations on it (`i++`).

You need to either make your integer a string:

```
var a = del_array.indexOf(i.toString());
```

... or make `del_array` a list of integers:

```
del_array = del_array.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x); });
var a = del_array.indexOf(i);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, Working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**simple example of indexof() are:--**

```html
<script>
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', '123', 'xyz'];
console.log("Array index"+" "+arr.indexOf('b')); 
alert("Array index"+" "+arr.indexOf('b'));
</script>
```